# XPath doesn't work on subset in context but does in isolation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

On the following XML:

```
<root>
    <h1">Annual Expense</h1>
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Fees</td>
                <td>1.06%</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><b>Total:</b></td>
                <td class="right-align"><b>
                    <span class="summary-line">
                        1.57%
                    </span>
                </b></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</root>
```

I'm trying to get the Total value (1.57%).  If I XPath query with `//tr[preceding::h1[1][contains(text(), "Expense")]]/td[preceding-sibling::td/descendant-or-self::*[contains(text() , "Total")]]` I get the desired XML block:

```
<td class="right-align">
    <b>
        <span class="summary-line">
            1.57%
        </span>
    </b>
</td>
```

And if I query for `//*[not(*)]/text()` against that block in isolation I get the desired result ("1.57%").

However, if I append try to concatenate the two queries (i.e., `//tr[preceding::h1[1][contains(text(), "Expense")]]/td[preceding-sibling::td/descendant-or-self::*[contains(text() , "Total")]]/*[not(*)]/text()`) and run against the full XML I get an empty result.  Why?

Comment: The `td` element contains a `b` child and a `span grandchild so the child selection `td/*` does of course not suffice, you would need `td/*/*` to select the `span` element with wild cards or `td//*[not(*)]`. Of course `td//span[@class = 'summary-line']` seems more straightforward.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, that seems to do it.  I'm trying to keep it flexible, which is why I opted for the `*[not(*)]` (so the value can be wrapped in any sort of HTML adornment and the query will still work).  I still don't understand why the single-'/' variant didn't work.  If you can elaborate I'd like to accept your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path `//tr[preceding::h1[1][contains(text(), "Expense")]]/td[preceding-sibling::td/descendant-or-self::*[contains(text() , "Total")]]` selects a `td` element node in your sample which has a `b` child element and `span` grandchild and your attempt to add a step with `*[not(*)]` to that path would select a child element of the `td` not having any further child. There is no such child, a step with `*` would select the `b` element, a further step with `*` the `span` element so you would need `//tr[preceding::h1[1][contains(text(), "Expense")]]/td[preceding-sibling::td/descendant-or-self::*[contains(text() , "Total")]]/*/*` to select the `span` grandchild or `//tr[preceding::h1[1][contains(text(), "Expense")]]/td[preceding-sibling::td/descendant-or-self::*[contains(text() , "Total")]]//*[not(*)]` to select any descendant element not having element content.